# PCF8574T I2C to 8bit Parallel

Tags: interrupts

I want to connect 5 of pcf8574t on my AVR ATMEGA32L. One for LCD 2x16 and 4 for general purpose I/O. The question is: if i get an interrupt signal from one of 4 chips, how can i know which chip has send the interrupt?

I think that circuit may be usefull to apart interrupt signal.
[image]

This circuit x4 times (one from each PCF8574T chip). "mcu Interrupt pin" connected together to AVR Global Interrupt pin, such as INT0, or INT1. "PINx mcu" pin, connected seperate to a GPIO pin of AVR such as PB7, PB6, PB5, PB4. and "PCF INT OpenDrain" connected also seperate to INT pin of PCF8574T.

but i don't know if this circuit it's working 100% .

Comment: Because they'll be connected to separate interrupt lines?

Comment: I have only one interrupt line. i try to make a simple circuit which aparts the interrupt signals, connected INT pin of PCF to a PORT pin and from this point a GATE of P-Channel MOSFET which make the switching to INT pin of mcu

Comment: Why not use the internal pullups?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately the PCF8574T does not provide a mechanism for polling the chip to see if an interrupt has been generated. You may want to consider using a chip such as the MCP23017 which does (via the INTFx registers).

Or if, as your new edit shows, you're connecting the interrupt outputs to GPIOs *anyways* then just use the PCINT capabilities of the MCU to detect the interrupt.

Comment: may this circuit help me to find which PCF8574T makes the interrupt, just to consider the Value of a PORT?
For example: One of PCF (e.g first) makes a Interrupt, this triggered the INT line of my mcu. Then just considering a PORT (PORTB) to see the value we found a interrupt, (e.g. value of 0111 of portb shows chip 1 has interrupt)

Comment: AVR inputs don't latch.